# Highcharts legend events without displaying a legend

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Is it possible to trigger this event which is triggered when we click on a Highcharts legend element (this one who hide or show a chart element), with Highcharts legend disabled ?

And in general, how can we do what we want to do with Highcharts event, bypassing the Hightcharts system (which is like anOption : { anOtherOption : aValue, .... ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Legend item click call [series.show()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.show) / [series.hide()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.hide) which manipulate serie.

Comment: Erf, this approach : http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/series-hide/ doesn't work with pie. hide and show are used one the $('#container').highcharts().series array which have a single element for pie charts
How can I managed with that ?

Comment: In pie charts, you have a single serie, so you need to refer to particular point like: chart.series[0].data[0].setVisible(false)